# Is it acceptable to show a specific part of video(s) where someone practices music and ask if there is a name to the movement they do with their hand?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So basically I watched some videos where someone was doing something I found unusual (the way they moved their fingers to press the keys on the piano), so I was thinking there might be a name for that.

I was wondering if it would be on topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this would be fine as asking for terms for techniques is on topic, but make sure you add enough description where it would be valid if the video went away. Over time, links and videos tend to rot away so adding more detail outside the video would be helpful long term.

Comment: For what it's worth, I realised that question was not worth asking. Good to know it's on topic though.